# Using columnar data in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, seaborn

I'm trying to create an And statement in my for loop. There is a data frame that I have under "b". There are two columns of the data frame that I isolated into their respective lists (cdr3_length and heavy_percent).

I'm trying to create a for loop where the it parses through b and adds all data where the cdr3_length > 15 and heavy_percent < 88 to a new list "candidates".

```
cdr3_length=marv["heavy_cdr3_aa_length"]
cdr3_length.head()
heavy_percent=marv["heavy_percent_id"]
heavy_percent.head()

cnt_=0
candidates=[]
for i in range(0, len(b)):
    if (cdr3_length(b[i]) > 15 & heavy_percent(b[i]) < 88
    candidates.append(b[i])

cnt_+=1
```

I am getting a syntax error in the if statement line, but I can't find it. I appreciate any hep given!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (cdr3_length(b[i]) > 15 & heavy_percent(b[i]) < 88
candidates.append(b[i])
```

->

```
if (cdr3_length(b[i]) > 15) and (heavy_percent(b[i]) < 88):
    candidates.append(b[i])
```

python uses indentation to form blocks of code, so you should watch this closely. Also you may want to visit python.org an read its awesome beginners guide. While both typing an syntax are both relaxed in this language they still demand respect

Comment: Thank you! It seems the syntax error has been resolved,  but now it is saying I have a KeyError: 0. I'm not sure what's not defined here, as candidates was created as an empty list before I started writing the For loop. Much thanks for your time, I'm definitely going to check out the beginners guide.